# If I connect 3 12V batteries in parallel to eachother, then connect them to the load, am I connecting to the Load in parallel or series?

Tags: circuit-analysis, current, current-measurement, parallel, series

I have 3 12V batteries. I have connected the 12V batteries in parallel to each other. I have 1 positive lead and 1 negative lead coming off to my motor.

Am I connecting to that motor in parallel or in series?

My understanding is that I am connecting my batteries to EACHOTHER in parallel, therefore its still 12V but will be slower to drain, but to my motor in series. The difference being if I was connecting to my motor in parallel, I would have 3 leads going to the positive and 3 to the negative?

I am trying to work this out as I am trying to workout whether my motor is going to have a higher current going to it (e.g. the case if motor is connected in parallel) or if the current would be the same (e.g. if motor connected in series)

Comment: It's only words. The circuit doesn't care what words you use.

Comment: how can the current possibly change depending on the label you put on a circuit?

Answer (score 0):

Generally when we talk of **series** connected components we mean components connected between power rails. In this case your battery assembly provides the power rails and there is only one component, the motor, connected between them. Series / parallel isn't really relevant.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5iNSS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. In this schematic it's obvious that all the elements are in parallel.*

> I am trying to workout whether my motor is going to have a higher current going to it (e.g. the case if motor is connected in parallel) or if the current would be the same (e.g. if motor connected in series).

Regardless of whether one thinks of this as a series or parallel connection it should be obvious that there is 12 V across the motor. If any one or two of the batteries were able to supply the required current then the motor will behave the same with one, two or three batteries connected in parallel.

---

There will be someone along shortly to argue that it can be considered a series connection.

Comment: I already did mention in my answer it can be considered in any way and it does not matter. Two items connected together in a ring can be either.

Comment: Depending upon the battery technology, are there any safety issues with connecting three 12 V batteries in parallel? E.g. if not all batteries have the same voltage could the battery with the highest voltage attempt to "charge" the batteries at a lower voltage at a potentially high current.

Comment: @ChesterGillon Yes, of course it would. E.g. Connecting an empty car battery to a fully charged one could melt the wires used for jump starting unless they are rated to handle the huge currents. Also connecting batteries physically with wires like presented in this diagram, will stress the battery nearest the load more, because wires between batteries have resistance.

Comment: @ChesterGillon yes, problems. When first building a parallel pack, if the battery voltages are not equal, equalise them by connecting them together with resistors to limit the charging current. For many batteries in parallel, a fuse per battery is a good investment, so that a short-circuit fault in one battery does not result in the others supplying a damaging current to it.

Answer (score 0):

"Is the load in parallel or in series" isn't really a meaningful question, and the assumptions in the third and fourth paragraphs are mistaken.

But yes, the batteries are in parallel with one another. The effective capacity is higher, but the load sees the same voltage that it would with a single battery.

Answer (score 0):

If you think about the three batteries being a single pack, then you have only two things connected together, the pack and the motor.

Topologically, two items connected together in a loop can be thought to be in parallel or series, so that is irrelevant because the two way to think about the connections are identical.

Your motor will anyway have 12V over it and take whatever current it needs to run, so it is also irrelevant if you have one or multiple batteries.

The multiple batteries in parallel can just be thought as single battery with 3x the capacity of one individual battery.

So the current will be identical, regardless of how many batteries you parallelize.